# To prove triangle inequality for $d : \mathbb C \times \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ ; $d(x,y):=\frac {|x-y|} {\sqrt{1+|x|^2}+\sqrt{1+|y|^2}}$

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

Is the function $d : \mathbb C \times \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ defined by $d(x,y):=\dfrac {|x-y|} {\sqrt{1+|x|^2}+\sqrt{1+|y|^2}}$ a metric ? I can easily prove it is symmetric and positive-definite ; but cant make any headway towards the triangle inequality . Please help

Comment: Are you sure that there is a PLUS-sign between the two square roots in the denominator? Usually, there is a times-sign...

Comment: @sranthrop: I am aware of the multiplication sign ; but here it is plus ; I myself am not very sure whether it is a metric or not ...

Comment: Please, do not use \dfrac in titles, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles/).