# let $d=\frac{2|X-Y|}{(\sqrt(1+|X|^2)+\sqrt(1+|Y|^2)}$ where $X,Y$ are complex numbers.prove that this is metric space .

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $$d=\frac{2|x-y|}{(\sqrt{(1+|x|^2)}+\sqrt{(1+|y|^2)}},x,y \in \mathbb{C}$$ Prove that this is metric on $\mathbb{C}$ .

I am having trouble in showing triangle inequality.

Any hints will be appreciated!!

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: This [has been asked before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104145/proving-that-the-triangle-inequality-holds-for-a-metric-on-mathbbc), without getting an answer. Where does that expression come from? If in the denominator one has the product $\sqrt{1 + \lvert x\rvert^2}\cdot \sqrt{1 + \lvert y\rvert^2}$ instead of the sum, it's the standard chordal metric. Can it be that it was just a typo in your source and the chordal metric was intended?

Comment: @DanielFischer its sum ,not product .

Comment: Yes. I wrote "_if_ […] one has the product […] instead of the sum". Where does your expression come from?

Comment: @DanielFischer Its not typo

Comment: Okay, how do you know that? And please, say where you got this expression from. That could help in proving (or disproving) the claim.

Comment: @DanielFischer this question is in my book.in which he asked to prove it metric space.

Comment: And which book is that? What is its topic?

Comment: @DanielFischer its local book on metric space .if you have doubt than you can prove it that it is not a metric space .

Comment: Looking at the fate of the previous question, it seems it's not easy to either prove it's a metric or to disprove it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49550/discussion-between-eklavya-and-daniel-fischer).