# How to show the triangle inequality for the following metric

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces, triangles

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$ and 
$d(x,y)=\frac{2|{x-y}|}{\sqrt{1+|{x}|^2}+\sqrt{1+|y|^2}}$
 I am unable to show the triangle inequality for this metric.

Comment: Have to tried the 'stupid' approach of just writing it out and show that the inequality holds by using equivalence manipulations?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104145/proving-that-the-triangle-inequality-holds-for-a-metric-on-mathbbc

Comment: Interesting. I would have assumed that there is an easy trick. But it seems overly complicated.

Comment: @MartinR, true, I deleted my second answer. Thanks for the comment.